# Access Base Page property from Master Base Page class

Tags: asp.net

Hi all and thanks in advance.

I have created a base page that defines two classes, one that manages variables for the pages themselves and one that manages the output of the Master pages:

```
 public class MyBasePage : BasePage
 {
      public bool IsEmployee;

      protected new void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          base.Page_Init(sender,e);
          IsEmployee = GetEmployee();
      }
 }

 public class MyMasterBasePage : BaseMasterPage
 {
     public new void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          base.Page_Init(sender,e);
          session = GetSession();
     }
 }
```

I need to access the IsEmployee from the master page. I tried actually calling an instance of the base page on the master page and then trying to invoke it but the bool comes back false and I tried to do the same directly from the class with the same results. I could put the values into session but I really don't want to do that. Is there another way to access the variable?

Comment: Why are you setting an `IsEmployee` property on the master page? That doesn't make much sense from a design standpoint.

Comment: I have some items that display in nested master pages that I need to control based on that permission. If there is a better way to achieve this goal then I would like to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyMasterBasePage : BaseMasterPage
{
  ...
  private bool IsEmployee
  {
    get
    {
      if (Page is MyBasePage)
        return ((MyBasePage)Page).IsEmployee;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Update:

```
public class MyBasePage : BasePage
{
  public bool? isEmployee;
  public bool IsEmployee
  {
    get
    {
      if (!isEmployee.HasValue)
      {
        isEmployee.Value = GetEmployee();
      }
      return isEmployee.Value;
    }
  }

}
```

And remove line

```
IsEmployee = GetEmployee();
```

from `MyBasePage.Page_Init`.

Comment: This code does allow me to access the base page value, however, I have discovered that I have an additional problem in that the method that actually populates IsEmployee is only firing after the get statement to populate IsEmployee on the master page has run so I still am not getting the correct the value.

Comment: You can check the order in which `Page_Init` methods of master and content pages are called by placing breakpoints in these methods - I don't recall what this order is. To get around this, make `MyBasePage.IsEmployee` property on-demand. See answer update.